# Handsontable Select2 Dropdown Options Change For Next Row

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, handsontable

Please check the following fiddle for a working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jepod675/2/

My data is following:

```
var countries = [{id:'1',text:'Country 1'},{id:'2',text:'Country 2'}];

var states = [];

states[1] = [{id:'1',text:'C1 State 1'},{id:'2',text:'C1 State 2'}];
states[2] = [{id:'3',text:'C2 State 1'},{id:'4',text:'C2 State 2'}];
```

Steps to product the issue:

1. Select 'Country 1' in first row and 'C1 State 1' in under State Column
2. Select 'Country 2' in next row.

Note that value changed in place of 'C1 State 1' to 1 (id of the State instead of name.

You can also see options of State in first row (refer screenshot).

[image]

I guess handsontable maintains one instance of options per column.

Developer's comment at https://github.com/trebuchetty/Handsontable-select2-editor/issues/15#issuecomment-144553584

> I'm not sure how to solve this one. Handsontable keeps the one
>   instance alive per column. You might need to override this behavior,
>   which I think is possible, but there would be performance penalty
>   associated with that. You might need to validate the other column's
>   value before opening the editor so that you could replace the
>   selection list with the correct list.

I am looking for help on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using select2 editor, the editor has callback method "onBeginEditing"

```
$("#hot").handsontable({           
        onBeginEditing: function () {
            var activeEditor = instance.getActiveEditor();
            var selectedRow = activeEditor.cellProperties.row
            var selectedColumn = activeEditor.cellProperties.col;
            if ( selectedColumn == 3) {
                var tester = instance.getDataAtCell(selectedRow, 14);
                var filterlist = [];
                var optionsList = activeEditor.options.data;
                for (var index = 0; index < optionsList.length; index++) {
                    if (tester == optionsList[index].tester) {
                        filterlist.push(optionsList[index]);
                    }
                }
                activeEditor.options.data = filterlist;
            }
        });
```